# How to selecting data from two queries using union?

Tags: mysql, database-design, php, source-code

I have three tables. I am trying to taking the data with two times interval after then subtracting from first two second for every possible row and getting the ledger report.

Solution is given by: **jkavalik**
[Solved MySql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b66a3/24)

My Problem
[MYSQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b66a3/1)

My simple query run and gives me some data:

```
  SELECT lh.group_id,lh.opening_balance,lh.ledger_head_id,sum(dc.debit)
    AS sum_dr,sum(dc.credit) AS sum_cr FROM ac_debit_credit dc 
    INNER JOIN ac_transaction_master tm ON tm.tran_id=dc.tran_id 
    INNER JOIN ac_ledger_head lh ON lh.ledger_head_id=dc.ledger_head_id
    WHERE (tm.transaction_date BETWEEN '2015/09/01' AND '2015/10/10') AND lh.group_id IN('8', '9', '56', '10', '11', '12', '13',
    '14') group by dc.ledger_head_id
UNION
   SELECT lh.group_id,lh.opening_balance,lh.ledger_head_id,sum(dc.debit) AS sum_dr2,sum(dc.credit) AS sum_cr2 FROM ac_debit_credit dc 
    INNER JOIN ac_transaction_master tm ON tm.tran_id=dc.tran_id 
    INNER JOIN ac_ledger_head lh ON lh.ledger_head_id=dc.ledger_head_id
        WHERE (tm.transaction_date<'2015/09/01') AND lh.group_id IN('8', '9', '56', '10', '11', '12', '13',
    '14') group by dc.ledger_head_id
```

But I need to execute this:

```
SELECT PF.opening_balance,PF.sum_dr,PF.sum_cr,PF.sum_dr2,PF.sum_cr2,(PF.sum_dr-PF.sum_cr) as cv,(PF.sum_dr2-PF.sum_cr2) as cv2 FROM (
SELECT PR.* FROM(  
SELECT lh.group_id,lh.opening_balance,lh.ledger_head_id,sum(dc.debit) AS sum_dr,sum(dc.credit) AS sum_cr FROM ac_debit_credit dc 
    INNER JOIN ac_transaction_master tm ON tm.tran_id=dc.tran_id 
    INNER JOIN ac_ledger_head lh ON lh.ledger_head_id=dc.ledger_head_id
        WHERE (tm.transaction_date BETWEEN '2015/09/01' AND '2015/10/10') AND lh.group_id IN('8', '9', '56', '10', '11', '12', '13',
    '14') group by dc.ledger_head_id
    ) AS PR
 UNION
   SELECT PV.* FROM(  
   SELECT lh.group_id,lh.opening_balance,lh.ledger_head_id,sum(dc.debit) 
   AS sum_dr2,sum(dc.credit) AS sum_cr2 FROM ac_debit_credit dc 
    INNER JOIN ac_transaction_master tm ON tm.tran_id=dc.tran_id 
    INNER JOIN ac_ledger_head lh ON lh.ledger_head_id=dc.ledger_head_id
    WHERE (tm.transaction_date<'2015/09/01') AND lh.group_id IN('8', '9', '56', '10', '11', '12', '13',
    '14') group by dc.ledger_head_id
  ) AS PV GROUP BY ledger_head_id 
  ) AS PF;
```

Where am I wrong in my second query ?

Comment: You want a JOIN, not UNION, if you need to combine columns from the two queries. UNION just unions the rows as if they all came from one table, but they are separate rows which cannot "interact"

Comment: @jkavalik, One of the part may exist data or not exist data, So what happen in join ?

Comment: That's what OUTER JOIN (LEFT or RIGHT) is for.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish, but I tried to transform your "union" to a left join http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b66a3/23

Comment: Thanks it works for me. Is there any suggestion for me ?

Comment: Check that you understand what it does and why.

Comment: this is not work when first part is no data, but works when change left join to right join, 

similarly it is not work when the second part has no data, but works when change right join to left join. May be needs to some modification. Could you suggest me for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not supported by MySQL.. That's where the UNION might be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9214674/1786423 - or just send both versions if you do not know beforehand which variant will and will not have data.

Comment: At last I have changed this according to your guideline. Check this fiddle   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b66a3/47